# Solution not breaking at User-Unhandled exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, objectdisposedexception

I am working on a workitem which gives an exception as

```
System.ObjectDisposedException:
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'TabControlWorkSpace'.
```

In `Debug->Exceptions` window, I have checked all options (under User-Unhandled) expecting that solution will break whenever exceptions occur. It has worked great for me in past and helped me to directly jump to the root cause. However this time, error occurs and I am getting exception window (with Send & Don't Send buttons) but my solution is not breaking on exception. May I know any workaround or something that I am missing. Please let me know If I need to provide any more information.

Comment: Are you handling the exception?

Comment: Hmmm....actually I am working on a product which is already built and huge. I am trying to find out which piece of code is behaving mischievously. and hence this question. Regarding handling, I am not sure if its already done. I need do more analysis. But of course I feel its not done and that's the reason we are seeing this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `TOOLS` -> `Options` -> `Debugging` -> Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"

Go to `DEBUG` -> `Exceptions...` -> Check all the boxes

Click the `OK` button.

This will break on any exception that occurs.